# What's the difference between "That's a monument for the soldiers that died in the war" and "That's a monument to the soldiers that died in the war"

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between:

> 1That's a monument for the soldiers that died in the war

> 2 That's a monument to the soldiers that died in the war

Comment: what do **you** think the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

Though both expressions are used colloquially, "for" implies the monument benefits the soldiers in some way. Being deceased, they don't derive anything from the monument, though their friends and family do. Therefore, "to" would be the better choice.

Comment: Moreover, "for" could imply the monument was given to them.